# false behaviour of is_base_of when used together with bind

Tags: c++11, bind, variadic-templates, type-traits

Using variadic template arguments together with a simple template argument I have experienced some strange behaviour of **is_base_of** when it was instantiated from a **binded** functor.

Here is the code:

```
template <class T, class Index>
class Base{};

template<typename T>
struct Checker {
    typedef int result_type;

    // Returns 1 if a given T type is descendant of Base<T,First>
    template<typename First, typename ...Args>
    result_type operator()(First&& first, Args&&... params)
    {
        return check(std::is_base_of<Base<T,First>, T>(),
                std::forward<First>(first),
                std::forward<Args>(params)...);
    }
    template<typename ...Args>
    result_type check(const std::true_type&, Args&&... params)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    template<typename ...Args>
    result_type check(const std::false_type&, Args&&... params)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

struct A {};
struct B : Base<B,int> {};

int main()
{
    Checker<A> ch1;
    std::cout<<ch1(3.14)<<std::endl;
    Checker<B> ch2;
    std::cout<<ch2(1 ,3.14)<<std::endl; // output is 1
    std::cout<<std::bind(ch2, 1, 3.14)()<<std::endl; // output is 0 but it should be 1 !
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is:

```
0
1
0
```

But I would expect:

```
0
1
1
```

Am I using the variadic templates in a wrong way? Is there any other (correct) way to get the first type of a variadic type list like Args? Why this is a problem only when it is used with the bind expression?

Note, if I am modifing the Base template to have only one template parameter, then the bind expression works:

```
template <class T>
class Base{};

template<typename T>
struct Checker {
    typedef int result_type;

    // Returns 1 if a given T type is descendant of Base<T>
    template<typename ...Args>
    result_type operator()(Args&&... params)
    {
        return check(std::is_base_of<Base<T>, T>(),
                std::forward<Args>(params)...);
    }
    template<typename ...Args>
    result_type check(const std::true_type&, Args&&... params)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    template<typename ...Args>
    result_type check(const std::false_type&, Args&&... params)
    {
        return 0;
    }
};

struct A {};
struct B : Base<B> {};

int main()
{
    Checker<A> ch1;
    std::cout<<ch1(3.14)<<std::endl;
    Checker<B> ch2;
    std::cout<<ch2(3.14)<<std::endl; // output is 1
    std::cout<<std::bind(ch2, 3.14)()<<std::endl; // output is 1 this time!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: May I ask why you are implementing this as functions instead of meta-functions? Involving a value seems completely unnecessary when all checks could be done at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately std::is_reference did not give me the expected result on a more complicated issue.
So finally I choosed providing the reference and const-reference overloads:

```
template<typename First, typename ...Args>
result_type operator()(First& first, Args&&... params)
{
    return check(std::is_base_of<Base<T,First>, T>(),
            first,
            std::forward<Args>(params)...);
}
template<typename First, typename ...Args>
result_type operator()(const First& first, Args&&... params)
{
    return check(std::is_base_of<Base<T,First>, T>(),
            first,
            std::forward<Args>(params)...);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious to know, what were the unexpected results?

Comment: BTW, keep in mind that a const lvalue reference will not bind to a non-constant rvale reference, so without a specific overload for that type, you would not be capable of passing a const lvalue argument without causing a compiler error. Only constant rvalue references can have anything bound to them.

Answer (score 3):

You're not getting the expected output because the data-type of `First` in your `Checker` function object when called after `std::bind()` is of type `int&`, not `int`.

Therefore `std::is_base_of<Base<B,int&>, B>` does not instantiate to a `std::true_type` for the call to `Checker::check`.

The problem is that `std::bind` is creating an object that internally stores the arguments for the function you are passing to it.  Therefore there is a named l-value as a non-static data-member of the object returned by `std::bind` that is holding the value you passed as an argument to be bound to your function. When that non-static data-member is then passed to the r-value reference at the time you call the `operator()` of the functor, it's passed as an l-value reference, since it is no longer a temporary object.  You would have a similar problem if you did something like:

```
int x = 1;
Checker<B> ch2;
std::cout<<ch2(x, 3.14)<<std::endl;
```

The named-value `x` is an l-value, and would be passed to the `first` argument in your `operator()` method as an l-value reference, not as temporary, since `first` is a r-value reference.  Therefore your type would end up again as an `int&` and not an `int`, and you'd print a value of `0`.

To fix this problem, you can do something like:

```
template<typename First, typename ...Args>
result_type operator()(First&& first, Args&&... params)
{
   if (std::is_reference<First>::value)
    {
        return check(std::is_base_of<Base<T, typename std::remove_reference<First>::type>, T>(),
            std::forward<First>(first),
            std::forward<Args>(params)...);
    }
    else
    {
        return check(std::is_base_of<Base<T,First>, T>(),
            std::forward<First>(first),
            std::forward<Args>(params)...);
    }
}
```

This will strip off the reference-type of the object and give you the results you want.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed true. But is there a way to somehow pass it as int, instead of int& ?

Comment: And why and how it became int& instead of int ?

Comment: Thank you Jason, it helped a lot.